# Best practice to prevent state update warning for unmounted component from a handler

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks

It is a common use-case to fetch and display the data from an external API (by using XHR requests) when a certain UI component (e.g. a `<button />`) is clicked. However, if the component was unmounted in the meantime, the following warning appears in the console:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

In fact, the most common solution ([approved by @dan-abramov](https://twitter.com/housecor/status/1093142219165499392)) to avoid the warning seems to keep track of the mount state of the component by using the return function of  `useEffect` to cleanup.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function PhotoList() {
  const mounted = useRef(true);
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      mounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  function handleLoadPhotos() {
    axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").then(res => {
      if (mounted.current) {
        setPhotos(res.data);
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleLoadPhotos}>Load photos</button>
      {photos && <p>Loaded {photos.length} photos</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, this seems to cause unnecessary overhead to keep track of the mounting state and to check it before every state update. This becomes especially obvious when Observables (where you can [unsubscribe](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription)) instead of Promises are used.

While you indeed can unsubscribe inside of the `useEffect` using the cleanup function in a very neat way:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // getPhotos() returns an observable of the photo list
  const photos$ = getPhotos().subscribe(setPhotos);
  return () => photos$.unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

The same smart cleanup is not possible within a handler:

```js
function handleLoadPhotos() {
  const photos$ = getPhotos().subscribe(setPhotos);
  // how to unsubscribe on unmounting?
}
```

Is there a best practice to avoid the warning without the ugly manual tracking of the mounting state with `useRef()`? Are there good approaches for that when using Observables?

Comment: I wouldn't unsubscribe. I would use the takeUntil operator on an subject that emits when unmounted. This will also effectively cancel the HTTP request so that the subscribe function is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are trying to fetch data in your component. This is not a good idea since the component could be unmounted and you would face many possible errors.

So that, you should look for other ways.

I always do async operations in redux thunks.

You should avoid your approach. Use redux and redux-thunk if you like. If not, try to find another solution to move async operations outside of your components.

In fact, you should be writing declarative ui components which renders for given props. So that, your data should be outside of your components logic too.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I'll consider your approach with passing all the data via props, however fetching data directly in the component seems to be a [valid approach](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/#react-fetch-data-axios). Further, I'm trying to [avoid redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) for now.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't prove that it is ok. In fact, it can not be ok. As you would face issues about unmounted component.

Comment: This answer didn't age well now, did it?

Answer (score 0):

That's an awesome question! This is how I would do it:

First, define a helper function (it's not cheating because it really is a highly reusable function whenever you're dealing with React and observables combined):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export const useObservable = <Value>(
  arg: () => {
    observable: Observable<Value>;
    value: Value;
  },
) => {
  const { observable, value } = React.useMemo(arg, []);
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<Value>(value);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = observable.subscribe(value => setState(value));
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);
  return state;
};
```

Just to help illustrate what this function does, the following component will display the latest value emitted by `myObservable`:

```
() => {
  const value = useObservable(() => ({
    observable: myObservable,
    value: 'Nothing emitted yet',
  }));
  return <span>{value}</span>;
};
```

Your component will then look like this:

```
export default function PhotoList() {
  const clicksSubject = React.useMemo(() => new Subject<undefined>(), []);

  const photos = useObservable(() => ({
    observable: clicksSubject.pipe(
      switchMap(() => axiosApiCallReturningAnObservable()),
      map(res => res.data),
    ),
    value: null,
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          clicksSubject.next(undefined);
        }}
      >
        Load photos
      </button>
      {photos && <p>Loaded {photos.length} photos</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the component is dismounted, `useObservable` unsubs from the observable that was passed to it. This makes sure that we don't at a later point attempt to set the state, and that the data fetching API aborts (or at least gets a chance to abort) the HTTP request.